# Unable to set cookie using AJAX call on DRF API

Tags: ajax, django-rest-framework

I have a Django Rest API that sets the cookie in a response object. When I hit my browsable API, the browser stores the cookie under Application>Cookies. When I try to reproduce the same result using an AJAX call, the cookie isn't stored automatically; although I do get a response object in AJAX call.

My code is as follows

**views.py**

```
class UserLogin(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.UserLoginSerializer
    permission_classes = (
        permissions.AllowAny,
    )

    def finalize_response(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Set Authorization in cookie.
        """
        response_obj = super(UserLogin, self).finalize_response(
            request, *args, **kwargs)
        if request.POST and response_obj.status_code == 200:
            response_obj['Authorization'] = 'Token '\
                + response_obj.data['auth_token']
            print 'COOKIE NOT SET'
            response_obj.set_cookie(
                'Authorization', response_obj['Authorization'])
            print 'COOKIE SET'
        return response_obj

    def post(self, request):
        """
        If serializer is valid.
            - call action.
        """
        serializer = self.get_serializer(
            data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.validated_data.get('user')
            token, boolean = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
            if not boolean:
                token.created = datetime.datetime.now()
                token.save()
            # user.login_attempts = 0
            user.save()
           data = serializers.TokenSerializer(token).data
            return response.Response(
                data=data,
                status=status.HTTP_200_OK,)
        return response.Response(
            data=serializer.errors,
            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class UserLoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserLoginSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.user = None
        self.fields[User.USERNAME_FIELD] = serializers.CharField()

    password = serializers.CharField(
        style={'input_type': 'password'})

    def validate(self, data):
        username = data.get(User.USERNAME_FIELD).lower()
        password = data.get('password')

        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        except:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                messages.INVALID_CREDENTIALS_ERROR)
        data['user'] = user
        user_service = UserService()
        is_valid = user_service.verify_account(user, password)
        if not is_valid:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                messages.INACTIVE_ACCOUNT_ERROR)
        return data

    class Meta:
        fields = (User.USERNAME_FIELD, 'password')
```

**ajax call**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('form').submit(function(event) {


       var formData = {
           'username'              : $('input[name=username]').val(),
           'password'             : $('input[name=password]').val(),

       };

       // process the form
       $.ajax({
           type        : 'POST', 
           url         : 'http://13.232.122.165/users/login/', 
           data        : formData, 
           dataType    : 'json', 
           encode          : true
       })
           // using the done promise callback
           .done(function(data) {

               // log data to the console so we can see
               console.log(data); 
               location.href = "localhost:5000/profile"
               // here we will handle errors and validation messages
           });

       // stop the form from submitting the normal way and refreshing the page
       event.preventDefault();
   });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The cookie is being attached but you can't see it from developer tools unless you're on the request url domain. 
Try logging in using ajax and hitting the request url (any end point) on browser, you'll see the cookie.